# Performance of calling a method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

What is the performance difference of calling a method using reflection vs. calling the method directly?

Context details:
I have a class, with some string properties and for certain properties I have to set the values to Lower case or to Upper case (and a bit of logic related to that).

I have two options:

1. either copy/paste the code for the 14 properties.
2. or annotate those 14 methods and using reflection find them and call them (also using reflection).

Of course with option 2. my code would much more readable and easy to maintain, but the question is about performance. I will have some millions (around 2-3) of instances and I would go with the reflection option, if the performance impact is not bigger than 20 seconds.

Does anyone here have any experience with that?

Comment: Reflection is expensive. You could find that out yourself by testing it. Measure the two options and see whether or not it's acceptable to you.

Comment: I know I can test it, but maybe someone already tested it.....

Comment: How exactly do you mean calling the properties through reflection?  Annotating a property won't change how it is called.  Are you going to be generating dynamic proxies?

Comment: @AndreiI Even if it was the case, the results would differ from those you can obtain on your machine (or the machine that will ultimately run your code). But as stated by Jeroen Vannevel, reflection *is* expensive so if performance matters, you should avoid it.

Comment: If the "more readable" option involves reflection, you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: @Pace I added more details on the option 2

Comment: Are you sure that those properties that you're trying to access are completely random and you *have to* access them by name? Maybe you can  add an abstraction layer or two and introduce an interface to access those properties

Comment: @resueman I really do not see but these two options. The problem is pretty simple I think. Do you have another design on your mind?

Comment: @AndreiI I understand that you are irritated by downvotes, but shouting in such a case is not proper etiquette. I personally did not downvote, but strongly suggest that you write a test yourself. Reflection performance depends on the JVM (and possibly hardware, to some extent), as well as your use-case.

Comment: @dimoniy those properties are pretty static (but relatively many) and are defined in an Interface, so I could improve the performance  by introspecting the interface. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to give a set figure because it will depend on many aspects of your system, so I wrote a class to check this.

The results surprised me, it seems for my system that for simply calling a method via reflection vs statically calling the method, static calling is between 10,000 for a non empty method and 1000,000 times faster for an empty method.

I used both just in case the java compiler/vm was optimising away an empty method call.

The code is below, also available in this gist - https://gist.github.com/piersy/23b4814eec806b584266

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestReflection {

    public static long INC = 0;

    public static final int COUNT = 100000000;

    private static class Dummy {
        public void doSomething(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
            INC++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        Dummy obj = new Dummy();
        Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", String.class, String.class, String.class);

        String s1 = "string1";
        String s2 = "string2";
        String s3 = "string3";

        //warmup
        runReflection(obj, method, s1, s2, s3, COUNT / 10);
        runStatic(obj, s1, s2, s3, COUNT/10);

        ///realtest

        long reftime = System.nanoTime();
        runReflection(obj, method, s1, s2, s3, COUNT);
        reftime = System.nanoTime() - reftime;

        long time = System.nanoTime();
        runStatic(obj, s1, s2, s3, COUNT);
        time = System.nanoTime() - time;

        System.out.println(reftime);
        System.out.println(time);

        //1000 *1000 *1000 nanoseconds in a second
        System.out.println(reftime / (1000 *1000 *1000));
        System.out.println(time / (1000 *1000 *1000));
        System.out.println((double)reftime/ (double)time );

        System.out.println("percentage speed decrease from using reflection:"+(((double)reftime/(double)time)-1)*100);

    }

    private static void runReflection(Dummy obj, Method method, String s1, String s2, String s3, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            try {
                method.invoke(obj, s1, s2, s3);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static void runStatic(Dummy obj, String s1, String s2, String s3, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            obj.doSomething(s1,s2,s3);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have run your code with Java 11. It is only 30 times slower. By adding `.setAccessible(true)`, it becomes only 22 times slower. The speedup comes from not checking access every time the method is invoked. For best performance, `invokeExact` a `MethodHandle` stored in a `private static final` field. It is only 12% slower.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, reflection is slower.  If by millions of instances you mean millions of calls then yes, in some cases you could incur more than a 20 second overhead.  In some causes you may not incur the additional overhead as the compiler will be able to optimize it out.  You will either have to give a lot more details about how exactly you plan on using reflection or run it yourself.  My GUT says that across 3 million calls you will NOT incur more than 20 seconds overhead however that is very much a gut feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with some drawbacks of Reflection from the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

> **Drawbacks of Reflection**
>
> Reflection is powerful, but should not be used indiscriminately. If it
> is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it
> is preferable to avoid using it. The following concerns should be kept
> in mind when accessing code via reflection.
>
> **Performance Overhead** Because reflection involves types that are
> dynamically resolved, certain Java virtual machine optimizations can
> not be performed. Consequently, reflective operations have slower
> performance than their non-reflective counterparts, and should be
> avoided in sections of code which are called frequently in
> performance-sensitive applications.
>
> **Security Restrictions**
> Reflection requires a runtime permission which may not be present when running
> under a security manager. This is in an important consideration for
> code which has to run in a restricted security context, such as in an
> Applet.
>
> **Exposure of Internals**
> Since reflection allows code to perform operations that would be illegal in non-reflective code, such as
> accessing private fields and methods, the use of reflection can result
> in unexpected side-effects, which may render code dysfunctional and
> may destroy portability. Reflective code breaks abstractions and
> therefore may change behavior with upgrades of the platform.

So you can take it for sure that performance would be an issue once you start scaling up.
But if you can live with the performance overhead which an intuition says should not be more than 20 seconds for Uppercase/LowerCase operations and being hugely scalable is not a concern  you can use it. But beware that intuitions on performance are usually always wrong. So you would want to test for sure.

Do look up Aspect Oriented Programming for the task you want.

My opinion: Use a AOP framework.